# How to upload a html5 video capture to sever?

Tags: html5-video, capture, ajax-upload

I got html5 video capture like this:

```
        var canvas = document.createElement('canvas');
        canvas.height = video.height;
        canvas.width = video.width;
        var ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');
        ctx.drawImage(video, 0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
        capturedImage=ctx.getImageData(0,0,canvas.width,canvas.height))
```

and tried to upload this capture like this:

```
$.ajax({
         type: method,
         contentType: false,
         cache: false,
         processData: false,
         async: false,
         url: '....',
         data: capturedImage,<----------how to convert above captured image here?
   }).done(function(o) {
        .....
   });
```

if just:

```
data:capturedImage
```

backend will get data value like:

```
str:imageObject
```

ajax request just send a str to backend,so how to convert this captured image to let ajax uploading work?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you tried using `capturedImage.data` or `JSON.stringify(caputedImage.data)`? The [data](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/ImageData/data) member supposedly contains the actual pixel array. I am not sure how `$.ajax` handles byte arrays, so you may have to do `JSON.stringify(caputedImage.data)`.